# does sitecore query support current() function?

Tags: xpath, sitecore, sitecore6

I get an error if I try to use the xpath 'current()' function in a sitecore query inside a nested expression, something like this:

```
/sitecore/content/Home/Topics/*[contains(current()/@MainTopics, @@id)]
```

What I am trying to do is, use this query as a source for my DropLink field to only list 'Topic' items that are already selected in another 'MainTopics' field in the same item.

But this gives me an error, something like `")" expected at position 50`

So looks like `current()` function cannot be used inside the nested expression, or entirely. If not, is there any way to reference the **current** node and not the **context** node from within a nested expression?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does sitecore query support `current()` function?

**`current()` is a function defined only in XSLT**.

By definition `current()` produces the node that is matched by the current `xsl:template` or the node that is selected in an `xsl:for-each`

**As SiteCore doesn't seem to have an XSLT implementation, the answer must be negative**.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it out, for some reason I thought current() was a xpath function. So there is nothing equivalent that can be used with sitecore query?

Comment: @Sudeep, I don't know Sitecore, it seems it implements only XPath 1.0. XPath 1.0 doesn't have *range variables* -- therefore it can't offer something like the XSLT function `current()`. Range variables are supported in XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any simple way to do this in Sitecore query.

But to place a data source on a template field that references items chosen in another field (if I've understood right) then one possible solution is to build a custom field. In the code for the custom field you would do some string handling to extend or override Sitecore query, allowing you to add a query type that specified a particular field ID. Essentially you'd have to write your own very basic query language that you could use within your C# code.

You can derive your feild from `ValueLookupEx` and override the `GetItems(Item current)` method with your custom query handling. As you can see, it quite handliy comes with the current item provided!

We had a similar requirement which we solved this way.

Comment: Thanks @james, yes this is another way of doing it, but something I wanted to avoid (extra work) for my specific purpose. Wasn't a  must-have, so configured my fields differently.